# pytest multiple apps with similar package and module structure

Tags: python, testing, pytest

i have the following project structure:

```
project/
├── src/
|   ├── app_a/
│   │   ├── routes/
│   │   │   ├── get.py
│   │   │   └── post.py 
│   │   └── app.py 
|   └── app_b/
│       ├── routes/
│       │   ├── get.py
│       │   └── post.py
│       └── app.py 
└── test/
    ├── test_app_a.py
    └── test_app_b.py
```

I usually structure my code like this where i have a separate "src" and "test" directory, and until now i never had any problems with this. But in this project i have multiple small apps which have a similar structure. The "app.py" modules from app_a and app_b both import the modules from package routes (get.py and post.py). The small apps run totally fine in their container and everything is good regarding the runtime. But now i want to add some tests with pytest.

I added both app directories in the proproject.toml under the pythonpath field like this:

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = [".", "src/app_a", "src/app_b"]
```

Now the tests run fine but the app.py from testing the app_b is importing the get.py and post.py from app_a which is clear because the path to app_a i before the path to app_b. I think i totally understand why this is happening but i don't know how to solve this problem!

Can someone of you awesome pythonistas help me with this?

UPDATE: It is not necessary to to cross import between different apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Solution*: Run your tests from the project directory and don't add anything to the path.

Like this:

```
cd project
pytest test
```

Then you have to do the imports relative to that project directory, e.g. in `test_app_a.py`:

```
import src.app_a.routes.get as get_a

def test_get_a():
    get_a.function_in_get_dot_py()
```

It is important if you have things like `import routes.get` in `app.py` to change that to

```
from .routes import get
```

with this method.

Also note, now you can't run `python src/app_a/app.py` anymore but have to run

```
python -m src.app_a.app
```

to run as a module.

You might have to add an `__init__.py` file to `src` or `app_a` folder for this to work.

---

If the apps need to import from each other, e.g if app_b does an import like `from app_a...` there are a few solutions.

1. The apps could be changed to reference from the same directory, `from src.app_a...` and run from that directory when run on their own using the `-m` flag

```
   python -m src.app_a.app
```

2. Relative imports relative to the .py files would work as well, e.g. in `app_a/routes/get.py` you could have `from ...app_b import`. This only works when run with `python -m ..`
3. Add `src` to path.

---

Thoughts:

- I'm sure there are other solutions as well doing something completely different, the python import system certainly has a learning curve.
- Initially I thought you could do this without changing app to a module and running it like that, perhaps there's a way, but at least this should work.
- Adding things to the path if it's global is messy, but that's not what is going on here. In general though I try to avoid changing the path if at all possible.
- Very good to have separate src and test folders.
- In my project it works to do just `import src` and then do e.g. `src.py_file_there.function()` but for some reason it didn't work when testing this here.

Comment: This won't work if the apps themselves (try to) import things as `from app_a...`

Comment: I added some solutions for that case

Comment: First of all thank you very very much for your answer. One thing to clarify, we don't need to import anything between the apps. So every app is completely standalone. For your answer i have to admit i don't fully understand it yet. I currently run my tests from the project directory and all imports in the test file are relative to this directory. The problem starts when i'm importing from app.py from app_a which tries to load the routes stuff. Without adding the paths to the pythonpath these imports inside the app.py are not working anymore.

Comment: that's not strange, I also did the import wrong. In addition, do you perhaps import it like `import routes.get`? you have to change that to `from .routes import get` then it should work when run with `python -m app`, I updated my answer